# Replacing all doubles quotes from SQL table

Tags: sql

Im trying to remove all instances of double quotes from an entire SQL table, and replace these double quotes " " with signle quotes ' '.
Is there an efficient way to do this? thanks!

Comment: Please make an [mre], and tell what error you are receiving. Think about your problem before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *change* the column names, you would need to `update` the table:

```
update tablename
    select column_name = replace(column_name, '"', '')
    where column_name like '%"%';
```

Comment: @mccull88: you should not mark an answer as 'accepted' if it does not solve your question.

Comment: @mccull88 this query is not changing the column name rather it's removing (") in your column.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select that column without any double quote in it:

```
SELECT *,REPLACE(columnname, '"','') FROM tableName
```

If you want to update you column by replacing all the double quote(") then Gordon provided you the right answer.

```
update tablename select columnname = replace(columnname, '"', '') WHERE charindex('"',columnname)>0
```

Comment: Maube also add `WHERE charindex('"',columnname)>0`, to avoid updating all row that do not contain a double quoot.

Answer (score 1):

To replace double quotes with single quotes, simply do

```
Update table
set column=replace('"','''')
where column like '%"%'
```